# Full screen widget-like webpages

Tags: web-apps, web-services, widget, weather

I'm building a TV display that will sit in a waiting room.  It is essentially a web browser that runs through a series of web pages.  We have some original content, but I'm looking to keep things interesting and fresh by adding some current news content, maybe the weather, etc.

Is there a website or web service that offers full-screen, large-text news headlines, weather forecasts, and other content that could be added to a TV display like this?

Comment: Might help if described more about your development environment? Like: Java Servlets with Portlets.

Comment: Would a dashboard like [freeboard.io](https://freeboard.io) or even [Node-RED](https://nodered.org) suit you? They are aimed for Internet of Things applications, but should fit well in a TV display. You need to do some (simple) coding thought to implement your features, but Node-RED has many weather/rss plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using a Raspberry Pi and [Screenly OSE](https://www.screenly.io/ose/).

You have control over it via "the cloud", you can post the content, content can include web pages, still images, and movies.

Answer (score 0):

## RSS Feed Readers

The following RSS Feed Readers take a series of RSS Feeds, and format them on a web page that looks great on a TV display.

- [Coffeedential](http://coffeedential.com/)
- [HeadsUp](http://headsup.news/)
- [RollGator](http://www.rollgator.com/)

## Weather

- [MSN Weather](http://www.msn.com/en-us/weather/maps/) -
  Set up the map type and location, then select the "Full Screen" option for the link.
- [YoWindow Weather Widget](http://yowindow.com/weatherwidget.php)